# Can I have more than one class containing the main() method in a Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I have a doubt about Java.

In a Java project (handled by Eclipse for example), can I have more classes that contain the main() method and consequently can I chose to execute one class or another class?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Yes, as far I remember one class cannot contain more than one main method

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: @NKukhar One class cannot contain more than one main method (purely because you can't have multiple methods with the same signature in a class), but more than one class can each contain a main method.

Comment: For what reason should it *not* be possible to have more classes with a method called main, or for that sake more methods called main within the same class, as long as the parameters are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have more classes that contain the main() method, but at least one class which contain main() should be public so that JMV will start that class as Main thread

- as the code written by **aUserHimself** represent

Comment: @AndreaNobili How come this answer is the best answer among all others?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect: A just as good question is why your answer got the most up-votes, as it is wrong? Just as when overloading any other method, you can of course have multiple methods in each class called "main". That's how the voting system here usually works. Being the first to answer a simple question will usually give you several up-votes no matter if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: @jarnbjo If there is some problem with my answer, I'm happy to hear about it. Please leave a comment.

Answer (score 9):

You can have as many Classes as you want as long as each class have single `main` method.

You'll have to be opening a Specific Class in Eclipse if you wanna run `main` in that class or you can choose previously run classes from Eclipse `Run` Menuitem.

`main` means `public static void main(String[] args)` which is entry point in java programs.

Comment: Would there be a best practice to allow the main method to be modified during run time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have as many `public static void main(String args[])` methods as classes. 
You can also have more of them in the same file. For example, inside `Class2.java` you can have:

```
class Class1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me sum up the points regarding main method in JAVA (which is confusing at the beginning).

**1. can we have more than one main() method in a class?**
Ans: **Yes.** You can have more than one method with the name main but different signature. These methods will be overloaded. **BUT** the main method with following sigature will be treated as app entry point.

***`public static void main(String args[]`***) which is same as `public static void main(String... args)` or `public static void main(String[] args)`

**2. can we have more than one main method in a java program?**
Ans: **Yes**. We can have different classes having the main methods.

Then which one will be treated as app entry point?

*While running a program with such classes, the user will be asked to choose among the classes to act as entry point.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have  more classes that contain `public static void main(String[] args)`. And you can chose to execute one class or another class. However, you can't have more than one main method within same class.

Comment: But only one of them can be the entry point once you create a JAR file from the project...